# Issue Routing along IPSEC VPN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, juniper, vyatta

I am struggling to get two different subnets routing along a IPSec tunnel.

The tunnel is between a Vyatta (6.5) and a Juniper firewall.

The tunnel was initially created to route between a subnet in our office behind the Vyatta (10.150.0.0/24) to a subnet in our offsite DR (10.250.0.0/24). However, I now also want to route another subnet in our office to the offsite DR (192.168.47.0/24).

I have added another tunnel on the Vyatta to allow this:

```
 tunnel 1 {
 allow-nat-networks disable
 allow-public-networks disable
 esp-group ***
 local {
     prefix 10.150.0.0/24
 }
 remote {
     prefix 10.250.0.0/24
 }
 }
 tunnel 2 {
 allow-nat-networks disable
 allow-public-networks disable
 esp-group ***
 local {
     prefix 192.168.47.0/24
 }
 remote {
     prefix 10.250.0.0/24
 }
 }
```

Also I have modified the security and routing on the Juniper to allow this traffic.

The strange thing is, this seems to work but for only one tunnel at a time. Both tunnels show as up and connected however I can only ever receive responses from the 10.250.0.0 subnet from either the 10.150.0.0 or the 192.168.47.0, not both at the same time.

Not quite sure where I am going wrong here!

Comment: What do your Vyatta logs say about the tunnels? `grep pluto /var/log/messages`